# In Production Server After Updating the files, Not showing the updated one for vue.js

Tags: vue.js, caching, production-environment

IN `Production Server` After Updating the files, Not showing the updated one.
It is showing the old designs in vue.js. In the server I am creating a build then run this. But Build is showing the old codes but the code is present in the production Server.

Tried using Clear cache, CTRL+F5 etc. Not Working..

Comment: Have you tried busting the cache by either renaming the .js files or adding a random query string to the .js file name? That'll verify if caching is really the issue or if you have another problem.

Comment: when making built then index file name is same as previous. where to change? plz guide.